# Return JQuery specific click in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how you can return the value of which specific child has been clicked within an index.

Normally the default behavior would be to use

```
var selected = $(this).index();
```

Although this works as it should , it doesn't return the index from INSIDE a function such as the following.

```
var selected;

$(container.children()).on('click', function() {
    selected = $(this).index();
    selected.siblings().fadeOut();
    selected.animate({
        width: 920,
        height: 440
    });
    selected.fadeOut();
});

//console.log(selected) = 'undefined'!
```

Why is this and what is the appropriate solution?!

EDIT:

Please note, I have edited this to make the question less specific and localized, in order for it to gain a better vote.

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
console.log($(this).index());
```

- http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: In the click function it is correct. Outside it is always -1. How do I return your answer from INSIDE the click function?

Comment: Return it to what? I don't know what you mean. On click, grab the index, do something with it. That is the typical pattern.

Comment: Before the click function I have a variable var selected;
Inside the click function I set the variable as selected = $(this).index();
After the click function selected is "not defined". 
Why not?